# Printing only the final odeint output

Tags: python, scipy, odeint

I am sorry this may appear as a pretty dumb question, but I need to ask whether it is possible to print only the final output value while solving coupled differential equations in odeint? Actually I am trying to solve two coupled differential equations for time intervals generated randomly and get only the final output printed for each interval.

Comment: Add a simple code example of your current code and the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last element of the array of y-values is `y[-1]`. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si
def F(y, t):
    return [y[1], y[0]]
t = np.arange(0, 1, 0.001)
y = si.odeint(F, [1, 0], t)
print(y[-1])
```

returns `[ 1.54190626  1.17365875]`. The exact solution of this system is y(t) = [cosh(t), sinh(t)]; the numbers shown are reasonably close to cosh(1) and sinh(1).